# How to catch `Warning: [react-router] Location "/non-existing-route" did not match any routes`?

Tags: reactjs, match, react-router

I'm working on a server side rendering app and using `react-router`'s `match({}, function callback(error, redirect, props){})`. When there is no route matching to the given URL I want to let the next middleware carry on. Right now I'm not getting any error (the error param is undefined) when no match happned but a Warning: `Warning: [react-router] Location "/non-existing-route" did not match any routes`

How can I know if there was no match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If all three parameters are undefined, this means that there was no route found matching the given location.

From the react-router docs: https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#match-routes-location-history-options--cb

So just check all three callback arguments for `undefined`.

Comment: Haha! I noticed that the parameter `error` becomes `null` when a route was found! Didn't know it actually means anything... Thanks!